# How do I search a file and return an array of the results and line number in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

How do I search a file and return an array of the results so that I can use it in a collection in PHP?

So, for example, say I have a .txt file with something like:

```
hellohello
hihi
heywhats up
hello hey whats up
hello
```

And I want to search for all occurrences with `hello` and its line number, then return it as an array so I can use it in a data collector.

So, it would  return the line number and line, like:

```
$results = array
(
array('1', 'hellohello'), 
array('4', 'hello hey whats up'), 
array('5', 'hello'),
);
```

My idea is to us `file_get_contents`.

So, for example..

```
$file = 'example.txt';

function get_file($file) {
  $file = file_get_contents($file);
  return $file;
}

function searchFile($search_str) {
  $matches = preg_match('/$search_str/i', get_file($file);
  return $matches;
}
```

Comment: I think you would need `fopen()` more, as it's allow you to read file line by line. Or use `explode()` on your file contents to break lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, you could also use `file()` function so it reads the entire file into an array. Then you could just loop, then search. Rough example:

```
$file = 'example.txt';
$search = 'hello';
$results = array();
$contents = file($file);
foreach($contents as $line => $text) {
    if(stripos($text, $search) !== false) {
        $results[] = array($line+1, $text);
    }
}
print_r($results);
```

Sidenote: `stripos()` is just an example, you could still use your other way/preference to search the needle for that particular line.

Comment: This works good. The only problem is that `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` means that the the code will return the wrong lines. I removed it and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @AAA oh, if your strict about it, just omit then it some empty line . sure im glad this helped

Comment: How would I modify the code so that it returns an object from an interface collection?

Comment: @AAA you could just break it up into segments methods, of course the first method, just provide the path, then just return an array content, then the searching part, just provide the array, inside it the loop, then return also the multi dimensional of found results.